# Bash Script in Sudoers File, But Want Said Script to Ask for Root Password Under Certain Conditions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo

I'm driven here by my weak Google-fu.  I found this question to be extremely difficult to search.

I wrote a bash script that checks for package updates to my Debian Wheezy load.  This is not a cron job.  I want the user to be able to run the script manually whenever she suspects (via an email, for example) that package updates may be available and then be able to actually download and install same.

If the script is run and updates are found, I want the script to then ask the user for the root password, then open Aptitude, so the user can see what package updates are available.

I have the script running on several hosts, but on one of the hosts, I want to have the script alert me if the host does not currently have a network connection before checking for updates.  For this, I use the "route" command, which requires root privileges to run.  I don't, however, wish to put "route" into said host's sudoers file.  So, on the particular host that I need network connectivity confirmation, I have referenced the script itself in that host's sudoers file:

```
booboo ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/booboo/Scripts/chk4updates.sh
```

Here is a look at an outline of what the script does:

```
host=$(hostname)

if [ $host = travel ] ; then

    ...check for a connection, using the "route" command...
fi

...check for package updates...

if [ ...updates are found... ] ; then

    gksu aptitude
fi
```

For all of the non-problem hosts, if updates are found, I get the gksu window that asks for the root password so that "aptitude" can be opened.  But, for the host named "travel", the script opens aptitude *without* asking for a root password.  I don't want this to happen.

I've tried a few things, but nothing has worked for me.  Do I need to modify the problem host's sudoers file, or can I add a command to the script that will give me my desired behavior?  Something like:

```
...
...check for package updates...

if [ ...updates are found... ] ; then

    if [ $host = travel ] ; then

        ...some command so that a root password is required to open aptitude...

    else

        gksu aptitude
    fi
fi
```

TIA!

Comment: Which distribution and version do you use? If your `sudo` command has option `-U` check its output `sudo -U booboo -l`.

Comment: You really need to be root to run `route -v`? I find that unusual, but if you can't use `route`, what about `ifconfig <interface>` (check if it is `UP`) Or if nothing else works, there's always `ping` to a known host, like the router. (Although that might bring up the connection, while route and ifconfig wouldn't.)

Comment: split the connection test on `travel` into a second script. Otherwise you are running `chk4updates.sh` as root (if I understand your setup) and any calls made in `chk4updates.sh` on `travel` will inherit its current environment `UID/EUID` and cause `gksu` to bypass the password check because it thinks it is called by root.

Comment: Cyrus, I am using Debian Wheezy.  Yes, my `sudo` command features the `-U` option.  The `sudo -U booboo -l` command tells me what I already know, that there is the line: `booboo ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/booboo/Scripts/chk4updates.sh` in the host's sudoers file.

Comment: rici, yes, Debian Wheezy requires root privileges to run `route -v`, or any `route` command, for that matter.  The same situation exists for the `ifconfig` command, I'm afraid.  My problem with using the `ping` command is that the `travel` host does just that...it travels to many different places...

Comment: David C. Rankin, it seems to me that if I split the connection test on `travel`, I'll be right back where I started.  Your input did inspire me to try to conduct the connection test using a sourced function.  I could not figure out, however, how to add a line to my `sudoers` file that would allow me to run the function without entering the root password to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are root, you can switch to a regular user at any point with `su`.

```
if [ -z "$SUDO_USER" ]; then
    gksudo aptitude
else
    su -c 'gksudo aptitude' "$SUDO_USER"
fi
```

Your setup seems extremely brittle and convoluted, though.  There really is no such thing as a safe `sudo` shell script.  The requirement to not add `route` to the `sudoers` file seems suspicious.  Is there really no way you can refactor this so that the special case is handled on `travel` somehow?  Maybe write a wrapper for `route` which you can put in `sudoers` and which checks that it's called from the right script, for example.

However, I would actually go with `ping` instead of `route` -- after all, `route` only tells you whether the route is set up locally, but won't reveal if there is a connectivity problem to the outside world.  Then the rest of your question is moot.

(Or maybe even use something like [`cron-apt`](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/162/A_short_introduction_to_cron-apt) and remove the whole problem completely.)

Comment: tripleee, I gave your comments some thought and you are right, of course.  A sudo script is just asking for trouble (unless said script is saved in the /root directory - then, you need to be root to change it or even look at it...).  Yes, `ping` is the command I was looking for.  Its use solved my problem.  I appreciate your time and insight!